# Appending service name in jQuery.ajax url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I was to set up future ajax calls using:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    url: '/WebServices/AjaxService.asmx',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

Is there any way I could *append* the service name in future calls? Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '+=/ServiceName'
});
```

Or is a global variable my best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the way you are suggesting (although `$.ajaxSetup.url` could be used that way), but you may want to create an object that has the path fixed and you can set the service method name:

```
function Service(){
  var path = 'http://myserver';

  this.getServiceUrl = function(serviceName) { return path + '/' + serviceName; };
}

...

var s = new Service();
$.ajax({
  url: s.getServiceUrl('myServiceName'),
  ...
});
```

Or something like that.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

`$.ajaxSettings` will allow you to access the ajax settings. You could then go:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: $.ajaxSettings + "/ServiceName"
  ... 
});
```

Comment: Do you have a link where I can read more about `$.ajaxSettings` ?

Comment: I just did a quick search and couldn't find one. I worked it out via debugging. I figured these properties had to be accessible somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean `$.ajaxSetup`?  You could use `$.ajaxSetup.url`.

Comment: Running `alert($.ajaxSetup.url);` prints out `undefined`. `alert($.ajaxSettings.url)` spits out the url.

Comment: Agreed, `$.ajaxSettings.url` works pretty well. `$.ajaxSetup.url` is undefined.